# How to transform a large data frame

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, transformation

I'd like to transform the following data frame, but can't seem to get the right function to do it. Any time I use 'melt', I am prompted to convert to an array, though an array does not seem to accept column names.

In any case, any help with turning this:

| A | B | C1 | C1.A | C2 | C2.A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC | 11001 | Core | Old | SE | New |

Into this:

| A | B | C | C.A |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| PC | 11001 | Core | Old |
| PC | 11001 | SE | New |

Would be greatly appreciated.

Code for the first and second df's, respectively.

```py
df1 = {'A': ['PC'], 'B': [11001],'C1':['Core'],'C1.A':['Old'],'C2':['SE'],'C2.A':['New']}

df1 = pd.DataFrame(data=df1)`


df2 = {'A': ['PC','PC'], 'B': [11001,11001],'C':['Core','SE'],'C.A':['Old','New']}

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data=df2)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Transform the columns to `MultiIndex` by using `replace` followed by `split`, then `stack` to reshape the frame to convert it into the desired format

```
df = df1.set_index(['A', 'B'])
df.columns = df.columns\
               .str.replace(r'^(\D+)(\d+)(.*)', r'\1\3_\2')\
               .str.split('_', expand=True)

df = df.stack().droplevel(2).reset_index()
```

---

```
    A      B     C  C.A
0  PC  11001  Core  Old
1  PC  11001    SE  New
```

Comment: Much more flexible solution. Nice!

Comment: Thank you. Could you please explain how the following portion works?:  r'\1\3_\2'

Comment: @Sam Glad I could help! **`r'\1\3_\2'`  is the replacement pattern** Here `\1` refers to the first capturing group which is `(\D+)` which matches one or more non digit character, in this example it matches `C`, similarly `\3` refers to third capturing group which is `(.*)`  and in this example it matches `.A` the same applies to `\2` which matches one or more digits

Answer (score 4):

With a little column reformatting, [`pd.wide_to_long`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.wide_to_long.html) can be used:

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'C(\d+).A', r'C.A\1', regex=True)
df = (
    pd.wide_to_long(df, stubnames=['C', 'C.A'], i=['A', 'B'], j='drop')
        .droplevel(axis=0, level='drop')
        .reset_index()
)
```

`df`:

```
    A      B     C  C.A
0  PC  11001  Core  Old
1  PC  11001    SE  New
```

---

Change the columns in `df` from:

```
    A      B    C1 C1.A  C2 C2.A
0  PC  11001  Core  Old  SE  New
```

To

```
df.columns = df.columns.str.replace(r'C(\d+).A', r'C.A\1', regex=True)
```

```
    A      B    C1 C.A1  C2 C.A2
0  PC  11001  Core  Old  SE  New
```

Then `wide_to_long` on the stubnames `C` and `C.A`

---

An alternative without affecting `df`:

```
new_df = (
    pd.wide_to_long(
        df.rename(columns=dict(
            zip(df.columns,
                df.columns.str.replace(r'C(\d+).A', r'C.A\1', regex=True)))
        ),
        stubnames=['C', 'C.A'],
        i=['A', 'B'],
        j='drop')
        .droplevel(axis=0, level='drop')
        .reset_index()
)
```

`new_df`:

```
    A      B     C  C.A
0  PC  11001  Core  Old
1  PC  11001    SE  New
```

`df`:

```
    A      B    C1 C1.A  C2 C2.A
0  PC  11001  Core  Old  SE  New
```

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the other solutions already proferred, [pivot_longer](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/reference/janitor.functions/janitor.pivot_longer.html#janitor.pivot_longer) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor.readthedocs.io/index.html) is another option -> your columns have a pattern that we could take advantage of (some end with numbers, others end with A):

```
# pip install pyjanitor
import janitor
import pandas as pd
df.pivot_longer(index=['A', 'B'], 
                names_to = ['C', 'C.A'], 
                names_pattern = ['.+\d$', '.+A$'])
 
    A      B     C  C.A
0  PC  11001  Core  Old
1  PC  11001    SE  New
```

the columns in `names_to` become the new column names and are mapped to the old columns that match the regular expression in `names_pattern`.

Answer (score 1):

thanks for your code typing. I will take it. :)
Here are some ideas:

- you already hardcode the one-row result, it's a good start.
- we can use that code with a custom function, then use `groupy.apply` to generate a new two-row result (dataframe) from one-row data. `groupby.apply` will take care of the combination with your new dataframes.
- after that, reindex if needed.

first, we make a custom apply function for groupby:

```
def make_new_df_from_row(df):
    row = df.iloc[0, :] # df is each df split by groupby
    dd = pd.DataFrame({ #configure your hardcode
        'A': row.A, 'B': row.B,
        'C':[row.C1, row.C2],
        'C.A':[row['C1.A'], row['C2.A']] #column name with '.' cannot use row.C1.A
    })
    return dd
```

then, use `df2 = df1.groupby(lambda x:x, group_keys=False).apply(make_new_df_from_row)` to get result your want.

there is a screenshot from colab:
[image]

some notes:

- groupby accept a function which use index as input and split dataframe from the function output, here just use a lambda function, return index itself, to split dataframe by each single row (one-row dataframe).
- `group_keys=False` means don't return the key (grouped index)
- `groupby.apply` accept a function which input is each groupby dataframe, you can return a pd.Series or pd.Dataframe depend on your need. Here we return the two-row dataframe from your code typing (with some variable change)